# Preventing double aggregation in databases

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I am using the following query to aggregate a table.

```
INSERT INTO aggreagtion_table 
SELECT CAST(EXTRACT('epoch' FROM timestamp)/60 AS BIGINT)*60 AS ts, COUNT(aggregated_value)
FROM aggregated_table
GROUP BY ts
```

It works well, but a second run of this query would reaggregate already aggregated data.
Is there a solution to this problem which would never lose or double aggregate any data?

To prevent wrong answers I will say that saving the last aggregation time and aggregating only newer entries will lose rows added after the aggregation has started but in the same second.

Comment: You could just aggrigate on demand when you need the data instead of storing it into a table (sometimes not a good idea if tables is large).

Comment: If you can't aggregate on demand, storing the aggregated data and timestamp in a different table would probably be the best solution.

Comment: @Brad My tables are getting huge too fast to do that, I am forced to clear it every once in a while.

Comment: @Nick that is what the query I wrote does.

Comment: You're right I didn't notice aggregation_table wasn't the same as aggregated_table. So I guess I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: To speed things up you can add a column to the aggregated_table so when you insert it has the value of ts that you are doing this on:  CAST(EXTRACT('epoch' FROM timestamp)/60 AS BIGINT)*60   So then you will have all this in a table and wont have to run thi sfunction all the time, then you ust have to do a count and gropu by on that column (then you may be able to do it on demand then that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need to do is add an aggregated flag to the table and set that flag for each data value when you aggregate data (you will probably need to lock the table against writes when you do that to prevent a race condition between writing data and aggregating it). Then you would add a condition to your query to only aggregate data which didn't have the flag set.
So something like this:

```
LOCK TABLES aggregated_table WRITE;

INSERT INTO aggregation_table 
SELECT CAST(EXTRACT('epoch' FROM timestamp)/60 AS BIGINT)*60 AS ts, COUNT(aggregated_value)
FROM aggregated_table
WHERE aggregated_flag = 0
GROUP BY ts;

UPDATE aggregated_table SET aggregated_flag = 1 WHERE aggregated_flag = 0;

UNLOCK TABLES
```

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you! Do you know whether locking tables by hand is a standard sql operation?

Comment: Yes, locking tables is a perfectly normal thing to do, especially in a situation like this, where otherwise you could potentially get incorrect data due to `aggregated_table` being written to between the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` taking place.